# Replacing href,src in c# with regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a content tag in wordpress blog which will be moved to another blog platform where the tags are different.

I have been advised to use regex and have problems reading and replacing href tags  and so on.

Here is wordpress content tag:

```
<content>Bild 4. 
&lt;a href="http://www.mertidattleva.se/?attachment_id=63" rel="attachment wp-att-63"&gt;&lt;img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-63" alt="Uterum skapar mer" src="http://www.mertidattleva.se/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/016stor-300x200.jpg" width="300" height="200" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;Spontant sett smidigt.</content>
```

Here is the new tag in new blog platform which has same result:

```
<content>Bild 4 br&amp;ouml;dtext
&lt;img src="/image.axd?picture=016stor-300x200.jpg" alt="Uterum skapar mer" /&gt;
</content>
```

As you see new blog platform has lesser tags and i want to delete this information from original content:

```
href="http://www.mertidattleva.se/?attachment_id=63" rel="attachment wp-att-63"&gt;&lt;img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-63" alt="Uterum skapar mer" src="http://www.mertidattleva.se/wp-content/uploads/2013/04
```

I have tried to kill the content string with c#:

```
string replacedString = Regex.Replace(line, @"(?<=href=)", "\"ww2\"");
```

but have more problem: i want to delete href, rel, img class, src

How do i code to code in c# regex to get file 016stor-300x200.jpg to new string?

I want to rewrite the file too without success:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file.DirectoryName + @"\" + file);
                        writer.WriteLine(replacedString);
```

Comment: The real question here is who advised you to use regex for this.

Comment: @Jonesopolis _he comes_

Comment: Jonesopolis - my boss did

Comment: Aside from the difficulty of using regex to parse this, maybe you should think about matching what you want to *extract* rather than what you want to *remove*. Then it will be much easier.

Comment: Ignore your boss, and use a html parser.

Comment: Problem is the xml file will be rewritten with the new tag and the old tags gone

Comment: Try, for example `.*\/(.*\.jpg)`. The capturing group will have you file name `016stor-300x200.jpg` which you can then substitute into your new tag. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/gU7jR5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to parse HTML is, in general, not worth the effort. But in very limited cases, it can be useful. If it's the case that your input is always formatted the same way, you can get away with it. For your *one* case, something like this ought to work:

```
var regex = new Regex(@".*\/(.*\.jpg)");
var source = @"<content>Bild 4. 
&lt;a href=""http://www.mertidattleva.se/?attachment_id=63"" rel=""attachment wp-att-63""&gt;&lt;img class=""alignright size-medium wp-image-63"" alt=""Uterum skapar mer"" src=""http://www.mertidattleva.se/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/016stor-300x200.jpg"" width=""300"" height=""200"" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;Spontant sett smidigt.</content>";

var dest = @"<content>Bild 4 br&amp;ouml;dtext
&lt;img src=""/image.axd?picture={0}"" alt=""Uterum skapar mer"" /&gt;
</content>";

var newString = string.Format(dest, regex.Match(source).Groups[1]);
```

Instead of trying to remove what you don't want from your original string, concentrate on extracting what you do want. What you is the part from `/` to `.jpg` so that's what we are grouping. Then we just substitute what we've extracted into the new tag.

You may want to add some error checking. For example, checking that the regex really does match and that a group is extracted.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPy73z)

Comment: Ok Fiddle seems good, but how do i do to rewrite the file with dest value and delete original href tag in the file? I have foreach loop reading a lot of xml files and when i have deleted old tags i want to rewrite new tags to file.

Comment: With `@".*\/(.*\.jpg)"`, you are sure to get into trouble. Greedy dot matching inside a marked up document is a regexuicide. [Ignore your boss, and use a html parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164537/replacing-href-src-in-c-sharp-with-regex#comment61865010_37164537)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Like I said *For your one case*. Since the OP didn't give anymore examples. But it shouldn't actually be a problem because you have to match the `/` before it.

Comment: Why did you escape `/`? It is not a special character and there are no regex delimiters in .NET regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Because I was figuring it out in Javascript originally. It doesn't do any harm, but it can be removed for .NET

Comment: You do not always need to escape `/` even in JS regex. When it is inside a character class (I have not tested in all the browsers though) and when it is used in the constructor notation, you do not have to escape it. See [`alert(RegExp("/lol").test("Find /lol") + " and " + /[/]lol/.test("Another /lol"));`](https://jsfiddle.net/mkgazs9t/).

Answer (score 0):

Its a Bad Idea to use REGEX to parse XML or HTML Content 
you can use XML Reader or linq to parse XML files .
for HTML Files its better you use [htmlagilitypack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) in .NET
here is full example to loop through all the files and update the href and src
 make sure to check the null values before assign or reading vlaues

```
 string dirPath = @"c:\mydir";        
string[] htmlfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.HTML", SearchOption.AllDirectories);//Filter can be *.xml
        foreach (string filename in htmlfiles)
        {
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();

            document.Load(filename);

        HtmlNodeCollection linknodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");

            for (int i = 0; i < linknodes.Count; i++)
            {
                HtmlNode node = linknodes[i];
                var href = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
                //Reassigning href value
                node.Attributes["href"].Value ="put your replacement string";
            }


            HtmlNodeCollection imgnodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
            for (int i = 0; i < imgnodes.Count; i++)
            {
                HtmlNode node = imgnodes[i];
                var src = node.Attributes["src"].Value;
                //Reassigning href value
                node.Attributes["src"].Value = "put your replacement string";
            }

            document.Save(filename);
        }//end of loop all files
```